# Delegate.Combine and lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Suppose i have this delegate's declaration:

```
    private delegate UInt32 Feedback(UInt32 value);
```

And here i try to use it with lambda expression

```
    feedback = (Feedback)Delegate.Combine(feedback, 
        value => { Console.WriteLine("Lambda item = " + value); return 0; });
```

But i get error: *Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type*

But it works this way

```
    feedback = (Feedback)Delegate.Combine(feedback, 
        new Func<UInt32, UInt32>(value => { Console.WriteLine("Lambda item = " + value); return 0; }));
```

I have thought that C# compiler must do it itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
feedback = (Feedback)Delegate.Combine(feedback, 
    (Feedback)(value => { Console.WriteLine("Lambda item = " + value); return 0; }));
```

You must explicitly say the type of a lambda function, otherwise the compiler doesn't know what type it has. For example see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/12/14/c-lambda-type-inference.aspx

> One of the limitations of C# type inference is that you cannot use it to infer the type of a lambda expression.  For example, the following code will not compile

```
var f = () => 4;
```

Comment: Is it because *value* is a value type and compiler can't use Contra-variance?

Comment: @Yola how exactly compiler can know value is an uint ? it can be any type

Comment: @Yola No, it's because `Delegate.Combine` has as parameters `Delegate`, and by looking at your function it can't know the type of the parameters (what is `value`? a `string` an `int`? a `uint`?) and even if it knew the type of the parameters/return value, there is no equivalence between "similar" delegates in .NET (similar delegates = delegates with equal signature)

Answer (score 3):

Lambda expressions do not have type in C# unless you cast them.It's because one *lambda* can be convertible to more than one `delegate` type so compiler can't decide which one to choose.And also there is no way to determine what are the type of lamda arguments since you are not specifying them.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda doesn't have a type. It is implicitly convertible to compatible delegate type.

`Delegate.Combine` takes `Delegate` as parameter, Since `Delegate` is an abstract class without any signature, lambda expressions cannot be converted into `Delegate`. You can only convert a lambda to a concrete type which has a compatible signature.

If you expect the compiler to convert your lambda to `Delegate` type which is an abstract class and thus can't be instantiated --Which concrete type you would like the compiler to choose? You'll have to specify it.

You can specify the type explicitly like this:

```
feedback = (Feedback)Delegate.Combine(feedback, new Feedback(value => { Console.WriteLine("Lambda item = " + value); return 0; }));
```

On the other hand if you have the concrete delegate type in LHS, compiler will be happy to compile.

For example: Following is a valid c# code. Because you said the compiler that you need to convert it to `Feedback` delegate type.

```
Feedback feedback2 = value => { Console.WriteLine("Lambda item = " + value); return 0; };
```